# Add region column in movement data - alternative to retired rgdal package?

Tags: r, spatial, shapefile, terra, rgdal

I have a movement dataset and a map of Canada as a shapefile (.shp). An example of the movement dataset looks like this (the coordinates are projected in ESPG:5321):

```
longitude latitude DateTimeRounded
459663.3  7181890      2007-09-10
459734.2  7181938      2007-09-11
459680.5  7181933      2007-09-12
459640.1  7181893      2007-09-13
459605.2  7181897      2007-09-14
459928.7  7182175      2007-09-15
459855.1  7182104      2007-09-16
```

I'm not sure how to attach or show the shapefile, but if any one has suggestions, please let me know!

My goal is to create a new column in my dataset called "region", which indicates in which province my each data point is. If a datapoint is outside the borders of any province (i.e., in the sea), I want the associated entry in the region column to be NA.

The final dataset would look something like this:

```
longitude latitude DateTimeRounded  region
459663.3  7181890      2007-09-10   Manitoba
459734.2  7181938      2007-09-11   Manitoba
459680.5  7181933      2007-09-12   Manitoba
459640.1  7181893      2007-09-13   NA
459605.2  7181897      2007-09-14   NA
459928.7  7182175      2007-09-15   NA
459855.1  7182104      2007-09-16   Ontario
```

Originally, I used the package rgdal to do this, but since it has been retired I'm not sure how to go about it anymore. Would any one know how I can do this using other spatial packages like sp or terra?

This is what the original code looked like for reference:

```
setwd("CanadaMap/") # Directory for Canada Map
CANmap = readOGR(dsn=".", layer= "canada 5321")#File path to Canada Map
coordinates(df) = ~longitude + latitude #change longitude/latitude to what the lat/long columns are in your data frame
proj4string(df) <- CRS("+init=epsg:5321") #Use the correct reference system for your data
df <- spTransform(df, CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=44.5 +lat_2=54.5 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-84 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")) #denotes what CRS to use for df (same as mapCRS above)
df$region = over(df,CANmap)$NAME #adds column for region (which was province) 
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sf` package may work for your case.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Load example North Carolina data set from sf package
example_shapefile <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Generate a bounding box
example_bbox <- st_bbox(example)

# This is just to create random fake coordinates within the bounding box
example_coords <- data.frame(
  id = 1:40,
  long = runif(40,example_bbox[1],example_bbox[3]),
  lat = runif(40,example_bbox[2],example_bbox[4])
) |>
  st_as_sf(
    coords = c("long", "lat")
  )

# Set CRS of our fake data to match our example shapefile
# Check example shapefile CRS with st_crs(example_shapefile)
st_crs(example_coords) <- 4267
```

Once we have our data prepared, then it's only a few more lines of code:

```
# Get our results
result <- st_join(
  x = example_coords,
  y = example_shapefile,
  join = st_within,
  left = TRUE
) |>
  select(
    id, NAME, geometry
  )

head(result)

Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -83.27518 ymin: 33.9193 xmax: -75.91465 ymax: 36.58093
Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
  id    NAME                   geometry
1  1 Sampson POINT (-78.17492 35.05357)
2  2  Person POINT (-79.03105 36.47649)
3  3    <NA> POINT (-76.11417 34.39561)
4  4    <NA> POINT (-83.27518 36.58093)
5  5    <NA> POINT (-75.91465 34.83266)
6  6    <NA>  POINT (-77.34693 33.9193)
```

In this case, NAME corresponds to county in the North Carolina shapefile, but in your dataset would correspond to Region. Our spatial join specifies `left = TRUE` to signify a left join to keep all of our lat/lon data and fill in NAs if there's no matching region that the coordinates fall within from our shapefile. Note that the `sf` package uses data.frames with a geometry list column to store spatial data. Depending on what else you need to do afterwards, this may be fine or you may need to transform the `geometry` list column back into separate lat/lon columns.